# How to select non-repeating pair of numbers?

Tags: performance-tuning, syntax, random, sampling

Consider the following combinations of integers `comb`, where the integers range from `1` to `n` and weights to them `weights`.

I need to select `n/2` elements of `comb` based on the `weights`, such that each of the numbers from the subset repeats only once. I.e., for `n` = 6, it would be, for instance, `{{1,5},{4,3},{2,6}}`.

The example is this:

```
n=300;
comb=Subsets[Range[n], {2}]//Developer`ToPackedArray;
weights=#[[1]]*#[[2]]/(#[[1]]+#[[2]])&/@comb;
```

Could you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "based on the weights"? Do you mean a minimum total weight?

Comment: Your example `{{1, 5}, {4, 3}, {2, 6}}` gives neither the max total weight nor min total weight. You need to define your selection function that is "based on the weights".

Comment: @lericr : I was thinking of random selection based on the maximization of the total weight of the selected subset.

Comment: Well, again, your example isn't the max, so either your example is wrong or you're not being clear about what you mean by "maximization".

Comment: @lericr : how can it be wrong or right? It is just some reference example showing the desired result. As I did not specify the weights for it, you may assume that the weights are just 1.

Comment: Then what is `weights` being used for?

Comment: I'm totally confused. Can you re-word your question? I'm reading "based on weights" but then you say I can assume the weights are 1. I'm reading "maximization of total weight" but then you say that there is no right or wrong choice. Can you update your question to clarify these issues?

Comment: @lericr The first part of my question just shows what I mean by "such that each of the numbers from the subset repeats only once." because it may be unclear what this phrase means. It does not care about specific values of the weights. I said that the weights may take any value for that example because they are not relevant for it - it is not about weights. 

The second part introduces a particular example with particular toy weights.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `n/2` disjoint pairs of integers taken from the list `Range[n]`, then you can do this:

```
DisjointPairs[n_] := Partition[RandomSample[Range[n]], 2];
SeedRandom[17];(* Just for reproducibility *)
DisjointPairs[6]
(* {{5, 2}, {4, 6}, {3, 1}} *)
```

Comment: That's not what I asked for... I will make a new question.